# Populate data in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a table with two columns:

```
id_test1      id_test2  
1             Null  
2             Null  
3             Null  
4             Null  
5             Null
```

How can I update or populate the id_test2 as below?

```
id_test1      id_test2  
1             256  
2             214  
3             147  
4             987  
5             561
```

Thanks for any tips

Comment: Where is the source of the values for the second column, and roughly how many are there? Is this a beginner question ("How do I update a column using SQL?"), or are there special considerations?

Comment: No.  As I answered below, I did miss one important point that each id_test1 column needs to update six times to six different id_test2.  Ex:  
id_test1                id_test2  
1                       256  
1                       214  
1                       147  
1                       987  
1                       561
2                       256  
2                       214  
2                       147  
......  
......    
Thanks.

Comment: I think the update syntax is enough to update records as you require, you asked a sql question and are being ambiguous in regards to what type of programming language, frameworks, etc you're using to accomplish this. Because of that, no one can answer this further for you. I agree with marc_s.

Answer (score 2):

```
update myTable set id_test2 = 256 where id_test1 = 1
update myTable set id_test2 = 214 where id_test1 = 2
```

etc

edit:

Based on your comment, I'd just blow away the existing rows that contain the null values and insert new ones...

```
delete myTable
insert into myTable (id_test1,id_test2) values (1,256)
insert into myTable (id_test1,id_test2) values (1,214)
...
insert into myTable (id_test1,id_test2) values (2,256)
insert into myTable (id_test1,id_test2) values (2,214)
```

etc

Comment: Ooops I forgot one thing.  Each id_test1 need to update as follow  
id_test1      id_test2  
1             256  
1             214  
1             147  
1             987  
1             561  
Thanks.

Comment: Oops!  I forgot one thing.  It supposes to be the following for each id_test1    
id_test1      id_test2  
1             256  
1             214  
1             147  
1             987  
1             561  
Thanks

Comment: Are there any other ways to do in batch?

Comment: kekekela, you may want to edit your "wipe out" SQL statements. Instead of your delete statement, it should be DROP TABLE myTable

Comment: The syntax I've given is correct.  I'm not trying to drop the table, just delete the rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE test_table 
SET id_test2 = 256
WHERE id_test1 = 1
```

You didn't include the name of your table so I used `test_table` instead. This can be used for each record and is pretty SQL agnostic for the most part, meaning the syntax SHOULD work for any RDBMS.